# Composer require drupal/ packages doesn't work

Tags: composer, upgrading

If I run...

```
composer require drupal/token
```

...I get...

```
Could not find a version of package drupal/token matching your minimum-stab  
  ility (dev). Require it with an explicit version constraint allowing its de  
  sired stability.
```

Not sure if this is relevant, but token is already installed in my site, but is not required in composer.  I want to require (and upgrade) the module with composer.

Changing my minimum stability from dev to stable does not resolve the problem.

I am having the same problem with other modules when I try to run 'composer require'.  Composer always responds with "Could not find a matching version of package..."

Here is a question I posted earlier today that may be related: [Composer doesn't see that updates are needed](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/265900/composer-doesnt-see-that-updates-are-needed)

Comment: Does your composer.json have this in the `respositories` section? `{
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }`

Comment: No.  And it appears that adding that section has resolved the problem.  Go ahead and add that as an answer so I can accept it... if you like.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like Composer doesn't know about Drupal's packages, which suggests you're missing a reference to the repository in composer.json.

Add this and you should be good to go:

```
"repositories": [
  { 
    "type": "composer", 
    "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8" 
  }
]
```